# Data not being stored in Vercel Hosted database using Prisma in deployment

Tags: postgresql, deployment, svelte, prisma, vercel

So, I am building a project using Svelte
I am posting user inputs to a Vercel Hosted Database through Prisma and Postgres.
When I run this project locally, the information is saved into the db.
When I run this in production, the information is nowhere to be found, and there are no error messages (that I can find).
What am I missing?

Also, sorry if this isn't enough information, I can provide any additional information needed.

Expecting the new insertion to show up on my database, when running through the app in production

Comment: Did you change the connection string in the app or is it still connecting to the local? Show both connection strings and  configuration.

Comment: I did change the connection string, yeah. Both local and deployed are connected to the hosted db.